# await client.guilds.cache.get(g.id).commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i tried everything pls help me idk what to do
https://github.com/Wumpuspro/discord.js-v13-with-slash-command -- the code

````
      await client.guilds.cache.get(g.id).commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\handler\command.js:68:51
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\handler\command.js:67:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\discord.js-v13-with-slash-command-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:447:16)```
````

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? This is only supported in v13.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

With await, you need to wait for the function call to resolve before accessing values or calling methods on it. Instead, you need to put parentheses around the function you are awaiting if you want to chain.

Calling synchronous method on result:

```
const result = (await client.guilds.cache.get(g.id)).commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
```

Calling asynchronous method on result:

```
const result = await (await client.guilds.cache.get(g.id)).commands.set(arrayOfSlashCommands);
```

Comment: The 2 codes you provided return the same result.